# Proof by induction involving combinations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Prove that the polynomial relationship
$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} x^k$$
holds for all positive integers $n$.

I'm trying to use proof by induction, the base case is pretty simple, but I'm having difficulty working around the summation.

I want to substitute $m+1$ in for m which gives me $$(1+x)^{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} {n+1 \choose k} x^k,$$ and I know I want to break up the right hand side into $(1+x)^n\cdot(1+x)$, but the LHS has me confused.

What is the process like when working with summations in proof by inductions?

Comment: Instead, start with $(1+x)^{n+1}$, break it up into $(1+x)^n ,\times (1+x)$, and note that there is a formula for $(1+x)^n$ by the induction hypothesis. Now, multiply that expression with $(1+x)$ and see if the right hand side can be obtained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to break up the *left-hand* side, in order to use the induction hypothesis:
\begin{align}
(1+x)^{n+1}
&=(1+x)(1+x)^n
\\[6px]
&=(1+x)\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k
&&\text{(induction hypothesis)}
\\[6px]
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k+\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^{k+1}
&&\text{(distributive property)}
\\[6px]
&=
1+\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}x^{k+1}+x^{n+1}
\\[6px]
&=
1+\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k-1}x^k+x^{n+1}
&&\text{(index shifting)}
\\[6px]
&=
1+\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k-1}\right)x^k+x^{n+1}
\end{align}
Now recognize a know identity and finish up.

Comment: Pascal's identity, simple enough. Thanks